# PowerShellでInvoke-WebRequestの結果に対しForms[0]とは何ですか？

Tags: powershell

以下のサイトに記載のコードで、意味が分からない部分があります。
なぜ `$response` の `Forms[0]` を代入していますか？どういう意味があるのでしょうか？

[Form posts with PowerShell](https://blog.csmac.nz/post/formpost-with-powershell/)

> ```
> $form = $response.Forms[0]
> ```

また、以下のコードはエラーになります。なぜでしょうか？

```
$response = "aaa"
$form = $response.Form[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

直前のコードが重要です。

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $myUrl -Method GET -SessionVariable mySession

$form = $response.Forms[0]
```

とあります。ここで [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.3) が何を出力するコマンドレットなのかが重要です。ドキュメントの[メモ](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.3#notes)の項目には

> PowerShell 6.0.0 Invoke-WebRequest 以降では、基本的な解析のみがサポートされています。

とあるように、6.0以降と6.0未満とで挙動が異なります。それを踏まえて、[出力](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.3#outputs)を参照すると

> [`BasicHtmlWebResponseObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.basichtmlwebresponseobject?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0)

とあり、6.0未満である[5.1の出力](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-5.1#outputs)を参照すると

> [`HtmlWebResponseObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.htmlwebresponseobject?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0)

とメモの通り、出力内容に仕様変更があることがわかります。それぞれのリンク先をみるとわかりますが、5.1が出力する`HtmlWebResponseObject`には[`Forms`プロパティ](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.htmlwebresponseobject.forms?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#microsoft-powershell-commands-htmlwebresponseobject-forms)が存在しますが、7.2が出力する`BasicHtmlWebResponseObject`には存在しません。

質問者さんが参照されたドキュメントはPowerShell 5.1を対象に記述されたものでしょう。実際、投稿日は2016/06/27となっていますが、PowerShell Core 6.0.0のリリースは2018/01ですし。

Comment: バージョンが上がると使えないのですね。対策しようと思います。$Form.Fieldsという配列を送信したいのですが、$Form.Fieldsという配列を作って $Form.Fields['aaa'] = 1 のように代入するにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

Comment: @bew3g3hjjj スタックオーバーフローは一問一答形式となっています。別質問は新たな質問として投稿してください。また、解決した質問については、[回答の承認](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1735/) してください。

Answer (score 0):

$myUrlのセッションを保存する方法、フォームを投稿する方法としての$responseだからではないでしょうか。

できるかどうかわかりませんが、SessionValueを渡してusernameにaaaを代入する。